# How to overload System`StringJoin to automatically use ToString on arguments?

Tags: string-manipulation

I am using an overloaded version of the `StringJoin` function since years now, without any problem, as I've invested a lot of time and effort earlier to make its behaviour consistent and predictable (see discussion [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/dd110e7bae28dc47/aceb6fe1fffa5edb)). I am fully aware that modifying built-in symbols is not a good idea.

The new `StringJoin` automatically converts any non-string input to `String` thus I don't have to type `ToString` every time. It still threads over lists, i.e. `StringJoin[{"1", "2", "3"}]` returns `"123"`. Also `StringJoin[{1, 2, 3}]` returns the same, but `StringJoin[{1, 2, 3}, "s"]` gives `"{1, 2, 3}s"`. The code is:

```
toString[expr_String] := expr;
toString[expr_] := ToString@expr;
Unprotect[System`StringJoin];
Attributes[System`StringJoin] = {};
System`StringJoin[expr___] := StringJoin@{expr};
System`StringJoin[expr_List] := 
  Fold[StringInsert[#1, toString@#2, -1] &, "", expr];
Protect[System`StringJoin];
```

For me, it works as expected, and I am really happy to use it as it saves me a lot of typing. Though there is one minor annoyance I cannot track down. Consider the following example:

```
Append[test, 1];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, that the message is printed with `List`-s wrapping each argument of the printed `StringForm` (that is: `1` and `Append[test, 1]`). Interestingly, `StringForm` on its own works as expected:

```
StringForm["Test variable insertion: `1`, `2`.", 111, 222]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**: Can anyone explain why `Message` fails to print its result correctly?

**Caveat:**

Modifying `` System` `` symbols could have many unexpected side-effects. It happens for this modified `StringJoin` too (apart from the above example): as `Import` uses `StringJoin`, the modification causes a massive performance drop when importing e.g. images. For details, see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer**: because `StringJoin` has this little-known  behavior normally:

```
StringJoin["abc", {"def"}, "ghi"]

(* 
  ==> "abcdefghi"
*)
```

while after you overloaded it, the result is

```
"abc{def}ghi"
```

**Long answer**

You start by using

```
Trace[Append[test, 1], TraceInternal -> True]
```

from the `Trace` output, you can locate the following code:

```
StringJoin[(If[ListQ[#1], StringJoin["\[NoBreak]", #1, "\[NoBreak]"],  #1] & ) /@ 
   StringSplit[
       "Nonatomic expression expected at position `1` in `2`.", 
        System`Dump`del : "`" ~~ DigitCharacter ... ~~ "`" :> 
           {System`Dump`del}]
]
```

returning

```
"Nonatomic expression expected at position \[NoBreak]{`}\[NoBreak] in \[NoBreak]{`}\[NoBreak]."
```

Analyzing this code leads to the short answer above.

**Conclusions**

***Don't* overload built-ins globally**. Who knows what else you will break? There are other options to do what you want. For example, you can use `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` to create local environments, as explained e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/344/convenient-string-manipulation/377#377).

Comment: Pardon me, but it is not my fault if I mess up something that is not documented at all (though I will suffer the consequences). Generally I never modify anything that's built-in, but this function proved really useful throughout the years. Of course it's a PITA when you have to deploy packages to others...

Comment: So, Leonid, I guess you highly DO NOT recommend to put a `Flatten` in the 6th line to read: ``System`StringJoin[expr_List] := Fold[StringInsert[#1, toString@#2, -1] &, "", Flatten@expr]; ``

Comment: @Istvan The problem is that the system itself is using many of its own functions, to implement other functions. And Mathematica as a language does not have a formal specification, and is defined by its single implementation. In practice, I think it is just not possible to anticipate all the consequences of your modifications for such a huge system. Even in your example, the problem happened in a rather unexpected place, and only because you overloaded *a single* function, you could make a connection. Overload many, and it will go off hand. This is just my opinion, of course.

Comment: @Istvan Note by the way, that, apart from the above considerations, the way you overload `StringJoin` on lists is wasteful in two ways: it converts to strings even if an expression is a string already, and (which is much worse), by using `Fold`, it will have quadratic time and memory complexity in the size of the string list (similar to `Append` for lists), while the original `StringJoin` is linear. So, someone (this may be you) used to fast action of `StringJoin` on lists, will have an unpleasant surprise (perhaps without knowing that `StringJoin` was changed) - another reason to avoid this.

Comment: I agree to the performance-drop due to `Fold`, but the code does not convert strings to strings: `toString` does nothing when its input is already a string.

Comment: @Istvan Oops, sorry, missed that part. Yes, you are right - I wasn't reading the code carefully.

Comment: @IstvánZachar The behavior of `StringJoin` when given lists is documented in the third **Basic Example**, even if it's not under **More Information**.

Comment: @Istvan Thanks for the accept. I hope my answer did not disappoint you too much regarding the possibilities to use the syntax you like. I very much like the idea, I just think that modifying built-ins directly is a wrong road to take.

Comment: @BrettChampion: indeed, I did realize that later. @Leonid: Not at all, since I don't use `StringJoin` in heavy computation. Moreover, my question was answered perfectly :)

Answer (score 10):

I agree that a user needs to proceed with caution when modifying `` System` `` functions. However, once a long time ago I saw a Wolfram Research tech-support web-page that provided a way to overload a System function to patch a bug. My code below uses the same trick which is very neat!

```
$modifyStringJoin = True;
wasProtected = Unprotect[StringJoin];

StringJoin[args__] /; $modifyStringJoin := Block[{$modifyStringJoin},
      StringJoin[Map[ToString, Flatten[{args}], Heads -> False]]
      ];

Apply[Protect, wasProtected, Heads -> False];
```

---

This version has linear complexity. 
Also, if you ensure `$modifyStringJoin` is not `True`, the code above is disabled.

---- Going off on a tangent -----

Using  `Apply[Protect, wasProtected]`  ensures `ToString` is `Protected` 'if and only if' 
it was protected before evaluating the code above.

Notice I use the `InputForm` of `Map`, `Apply`, and I include (`Heads->False`). 
I always do this to ensure my code is not brokent if somebody evaluates

```
   SetOptions[Map, Heads->True];
```

However, I don't know what system code would be broken if you do that!

Imagine what would happen to the system code if you evaluate

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Attributes[Plus, {Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless}];
```

or if you overload `ReplacePepeated`!