# How can I speed up image importing?

Tags: performance-tuning, import

The following examples show how slow it is to load a simple GIF. Can anything be done to make it faster?

**System #1**: *Mathematica* 8.0.1.0, HP notebook, Win7 64Bit, 2 x 2.4Ghz Intel Core i5, 2GB RAM, w/ integrated Intel graphics chipset

```
AbsoluteTiming[Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];]
(* 
  ==> {1.3650781, Null}
*)
```

**System #2**: *Mathematica* 8.0.1.0, MacBook Pro, OSX 10.7.2, 2.4GHz Intel Core i5, 8GB 1333 MHz DDR3 w/ integrated Intel HD graphics 3000 512MB

```
AbsoluteTiming[Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];]
(* 
  ==> {2.549696, Null}
*)
```

Both installations are on local drives.

Comment: It takes only `0.16` seconds or so (via `AbsoluteTiming[]`) on my installation (8.0.1 on Xubuntu Oneiric on a generic netbook with an Intel Atom processor); maybe you should mention your OS, *Mathematica* version, and possibly the specs of your computer?

Comment: Is your Mathematica installed on a local drive or a network drive? File operations can sometimes be a lot slower on networks drives.

Comment: Please use AbsoluteTiming for benchmarking, Timing has surprises....

Comment: on OS X 10.7 and mma 8.0.1, this takes 0.2s seconds. This is with an SSD, though.

Comment: On my macbook with OS X 10.7 and Mathematica 8.0.4 it takes .4 seconds.

Comment: Hmmm. I think this is the case where a great many people can say: "Look, I told you". The performance drop is solely the result of [this modified built-in function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/how-to-overload-systemstringjoin-to-automatically-use-tostring-on-arguments).

Comment: Should I remove this question, as it is extremely specific (i.e. it applies only to _my_ system)?

Comment: In a fresh kernel, `Table[AbsoluteTiming[Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"];], {10}]` gives `{0.3580204, 0.0920053, 0.0880050, 0.0790046, 0.0680039, 0.0690039, 
0.0700040, 0.0920053, 0.0800045, 0.0610035}`.  v8.0.4, Windows.

Comment: I suggest to keep this question, in the following format: @Istvan makes his update as an answer. Then, we either close it or as mods to lock it. From that question on `StringJoin`, we provide a link to here, as a very good case. Because, overloading system functions is an appealing idea to many people, and nothing serves better as a good stand-alone example, like this one. No amount of warnings would be better, since those warnings warn against "theoretical" threats.

Comment: I think it makes sense to leave it, as a nice example of what can go wrong with overloading built-in functions.

Comment: "Then, we either close it" - I've cast a "too localized" close vote, as there doesn't seem to be a more appropriate closure reason...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The cause of the slow speed is the presence of a modified `` System` `` function: `StringJoin`. As this modified `StringJoin` operates at suboptimal speed (see Leonid's answer and comments [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1399/how-to-overload-systemstringjoin-to-automatically-use-tostring-on-arguments)), there is a performance drop of 1-2 magnitudes. So I did learn the hard way why is it a bad idea to modify built-in symbols.