# Specify number of elements instead of step in Table

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-construction

I think I have seen what I was looking for a ong time ago but I can't see nothing such in documentation.

Quite often, I would like to create a `Table` with given bounds and number of elements, rather than calculating the appropriate step.

For example, instead of `Table[f[i],{i,10,11,0.25}]` I am looking for something like `...[f[i],{i,10,11,5}]` where `5` corresponds to the number of elements.

Is there a built-in function/option for this?

Comment: possible duplicate [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/calling-table-with-custom-iterator?rq=1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6949/calling-table-with-custom-iterator?rq=1)

Comment: See especially Michael E2's answer down at the bottom

Comment: @Sascha That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Your answer with `Array` works, but it can be sometimes a bit more complicated to use, as I understand it. E.g.: `Table[Map[Plus[#, 2] &, {i}], {i, 1, 5, .5}]` becomes `Array[Map[Plus[#, 2] &, {##}] &, 9, {1., 5}]`.

Comment: try `Array[{Plus[#, 2]}&, 9, {1., 5}]`. You are right that `Table` and `Array` behave differently. I personally prefer the way `Array` works because you don't have to think about the structure you want to obtain rather you think about a function you want to apply for creating your list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with V10.1,

```
Table[f[i // N], {i, Subdivide[10, 11, 4]}]
```

or

```
f /@ N[Subdivide[10, 11, 4]]
```

will work. Note that you must give 4 rather 5, because the last argument indicates the number of *divisions* not the number of *elements*.

Answer (score 3):

For anything *rectangular* you can use `Array` as in

```
Array[f, 5, {10., 11.}]
```

which yields

```
{f[10.],f[10.25],f[10.5],f[10.75],f[11.]}
```

**Note:** As discussed [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764774/using-array-and-table-functions-in-mathematica-which-is-best-when) `Array` is faster than `Table`for multidimensional lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
f /@ FindDivisions[{10, 11}, 4] // N
```

[image]

Comment: `FindDivisions` actually entails the mean pitfall that it chooses divisions it deems "nice" and does not necessarily do what you asked for (e.g. first and/or last entry slightly outside the defined scope). In my opinion the [documentation for `FindDivision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) should have a "Possible Issues" section