# Expanding Matrix Expressions

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

I want Mathematica to recognize that

```
A.(-B.C)+A.B.C = 0
```

Yet FullSimplify and the like leaves the expression as it is. How do I get around this?

Comment: C is not a good name for a variable. As you can see, C is in black, indicating that it means something specific to Mathematica. Look up C in the docs if you want.

Comment: you could argue that capital anything is not a good name for either variables or functions in Mathematica!

Answer (score 5):

Check the tutorial [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html).

```
a.(-b.c) + a.b.c // TensorExpand

(* ==> 0 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can teach Mathematica to factor out any number from inside a dot.

```
Unprotect[Dot];
x__.(c_?NumberQ y__) := c x.y
(c_?NumberQ x__).y__ := c x.y
Protect[Dot];
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that it's very easy to break things or introduce a significant performance penalty by modifying builtins ...

Comment: People often don't realize this [until they get burnt](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing).