# Lexicographic ordering of strings in Mathematica

Tags: programming, text, string-manipulation

I recently realized that Mathematica seems incapable of comparing strings in the "normal" expected lexicographic order. Indeed, for some simulations, I need to process text directly, without fiddling with it, and I would like to have such things as

```
If["aaa" < "aaaab", 1, 0] (* ---> 1 *)
Min["aaaa", "deaaaf", "dfeef", "a"]   (* ---> "a" *)
```

and so on. However, as far as I can tell this is not possible. Am I wrong? Or is there any work-around, or way for me to use lexicographic ordering? Do I have to code it by hand? Mathematica is so good at getting stuff right out of the box I have a hard time believing it (but this would echo some other contributors comment here, that strings are "second class" citizens in Mathematica)...

Answer (score 13):

I believe you are looking for [`Order`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Order.html) and [`Ordering`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ordering.html).

The `1` indidcates that `"aaa"` comes before `"aaaab"` in canonical ordering:

```
Order["aaa", "aaaab"]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Here `Ordering` is used to get the position of the first element in the sorted `list` and the that element is extracted from the list.  This is equivalent to a "Min" function.

```
list = {"aaaa", "deaaaf", "dfeef", "a"};
list ~Extract~ Ordering[list, 1]
```

> ```
> "a"
> ```

And a "Max" function:

```
list ~Extract~ Ordering[list, -1]
```

> ```
> "dfeef"
> ```

Comment: And perhaps `stringOrderedQ[s1_String, s2_String] := OrderedQ[Hold[s1, s2]]`, so that `stringOrderedQ["aaa", "aaaab"] == True`/`stringOrderedQ["aaaab", "aaa"] == False`.

Comment: @Oleksandr That is noteworthy.  I chose `Order` because the OP was already looking for integer output (`1, 0`), and because `Order` provides more information in the case of a tie.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Why do you use Hold if you already have `_String` on the lhs?

Comment: @Szabolcs no particular reason. `OrderedQ` works for expressions with any `Head`, so anything without the `Orderless` attribute will do. `List` would have been fine, in fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
Unprotect[Less,LessEqual,Greater,GreaterEqual];
Less[s1_String,s2_String] := Order[s1,s2]>0;
LessEqual[s1_String,s2_String] := Order[s1,s2]>-1;
Greater[s1_String,s2_String] := Order[s1,s2]<0;
GreaterEqual[s1_String,s2_String] := Order[s1,s2] <1;
Protect[Less,LessEqual,Greater,GreaterEqual];
```

This will make your `If[]` example work, at least. Would have to do some similar override for `Min[]` and other functions that you want to work "naturally" on strings.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend redefining built-in functions globally. [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing) is just one example of how it can go wrong, and all the operators you overload are pretty fundamental.  You can reduce the risks by introducing local environments, e.g. like in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/344/convenient-string-manipulation/377#377) (which seems also generally on-topic to link here).See also [this discussion](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/alternative-to-overloading-set/)

Comment: It is not such a good idea to modify built-ins.  You never know what code relies on `"acb" > "def"` not evaluating (I certainly do have such code myself, which I was running today: I substitute in values for the strings using `ReplaceAll` from a parameter list).  See [scary example here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/how-can-i-speed-up-image-importing) and [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1404/12)

Comment: @Leonid Ah, you replied the same while I was writing my comment.  I actually happen to have used code today that would break with this modification.  I was storing "metadata" (parameter values used to generate them) in my data files in the `"string" -> value` format, and did `"param" > 0 /. paramlist`.

Comment: @Szabolcs You see, even knowing this very well, it is still easy to overlook. I am usually taking a defensive approach here: try to code such that things like that can *never* happen, and so that I could prove that with more or less mathematical rigor. In other words, I am actively looking for weaknesses like that it my code when I write it, because many times even a small chance for trouble was enough to get into it.