# Maximum tuple value

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a simple way to make a maximum tuple value (similar to python)?

For example, in python

```
max([ (1,2), (1,3), (3,1), (4,0) ])
```

returns `(4,0)`, using lexicographic order.

If I have a tensor in Mathematica, is there a way to take the max without flattening it?

i.e. a way to call

```
Max[ { {1,2}, {1,3}, {3,1}, {4,0} } ]
```

so that it returns `{4,0}` instead of `4`?

Comment: The simplest solution would be: `#[[Ordering[#, -1]]] &@ tuples`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Fair enough. Made it a comment :) Now if only we can get Mr.Wizard to also stop answering all the low hanging fruit... :D

Comment: @rm-rf I think this is an achievable goal :-)

Comment: @rm sorry, I'm the king of low hanging fruit, it ain't happenin' :-p

Comment: @rm okay, I waited 40 minutes -- with effort.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, it's been an hour and I've undeleted mine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear to me from the question what you expect for `{ {1,2}, {1,3}, {3,1}, {4,0}, {2,3} }` -- is `{2,3}` to be returned because it has the largest sum, or `{4,0}` because it will sort into the last place?  I am assuming that you want the largest sum *but* you want to break ties based on lexicographic order.  You can do that like this:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {3, 1}};

Last @ SortBy[a, {Total, Identity}]
```

> ```
> {4, 0}
> ```

Or more tersely: `Last @ SortBy[a, {Tr, # &}]`

If you just want the last element of the list after lexicographic sort you can use:

```
a = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {3, 1}, {2, 3}};  (* note inclusion of {2,3} *)

Last @ Sort @ a
```

> ```
> {4, 0}
> ```

But there is a more efficient way which is faster than a full sort:

```
a ~Extract~ Ordering[a, -1]
```

> ```
> {4, 0}
> ```

More examples of this last form: [(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2435/121) [(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2178/121) [(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7680/121)

Comment: @Oliver you're welcome; which interpretation was correct, if either?

Comment: I wanted lexicographic, so sorting or using ordering for fast selection is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would be:

```
#[[Ordering[#, -1]]] &@ tuples
```

Comment: This returns `{{4, 0}}` rather than `{4, 0}` (which is why I use `Extract`) if that matters.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Pffft... :) One can always use `First/Last`

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}};
```

Since V 10.1 we have `TakeLargestBy`

```
First @ TakeLargestBy[First, 1] @ list
```

{4, 0}

Get the two largest values together with their positions:

```
TakeLargestBy[list -> {"Index", "Element"}, First, 2]
```

{{4, {4, 0}}, {3, {3, 1}}}

There is also `MaximalBy`, introduced with V 10.0

```
First @ MaximalBy[First] @ list
```

{4, 0}

Answer (score 3):

We can, also, use [**`OrderingBy`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OrderingBy.html) that came with **v12.0**

With the list

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {3, 1}, {4, 0}};
```

we have

```
Flatten[list[[OrderingBy[list, First, -1]]]]
```

> {4,0}

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {3, 1}};

Last @ LexicographicSort @ a
```

> {4, 0}

```
a[[First @ Ordering[a, -1, LexicographicOrder]]]
```

> ```
> {4, 0}
> ```

```
WolframLanguageData["LexicographicSort", 
  {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

```
WolframLanguageData["LexicographicOrder", 
  {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Sort` and `SortBy[..., Identity]` for equal-length lists (and possibly this condition can be loosen anyway) seems to do lexicographical ordering:

```
In[54]:= data = RandomSample@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[{a, b}, {a, CharacterRange["a", "z"]}, {b, 
     CharacterRange["a", "z"]}];

In[58]:= data // RandomSample[#, 3] &

Out[58]= {{"r", "s"}, {"i", "m"}, {"o", "p"}}
```

So the max is just the last of such sorted list

```
In[56]:= SortBy[data, Identity] // Last
Sort[data] // Last

Out[56]= {"z", "z"}

Out[57]= {"z", "z"}
```

For numerical data

```
In[59]:= data2 = 
  RandomSample@DeleteDuplicates@Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[{a, b}, {a, Range[1, 9]}, {b, Range[1, 9]}];

In[60]:= SortBy[data2, Identity] // Last
Sort[data2] // Last

Out[60]= {9, 9}

Out[61]= {9, 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy`:

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {4, 0}, {3, 1}};

Last@GroupBy[#, Norm, First] &@list

(*{4, 0}*)
```