# Pick elements of largest absolute value

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

For example, given

```
list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}}
```

should return:

```
{-5, 6, 4, -9}
```

**Updated**

I found a undocumented function called `` Internal`MaxAbs ``,but it only accept two args，for example：

```
Internal`MaxAbs[2, -3]
Internal`MaxAbs[{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}]
(*
 3
 {2, 3, 6}
*)
```

How can I make it can accept multiple parameters?

Comment: To be sure: what happens if a sublist is e.g. `{1,2,2}`? You'd pick 2 just once or twice?

Comment: @PinguinDirk or even more interesting what if `{1,-2,2}` :)

Comment: @Kuba, Just pick once, if `{1,-2,2}` should return `2`.

Comment: @explorer `-2` is single result which fits too:) My `MapIndexed` method will give you the first of "equal" numbers. Switching to `<=` will result in the last one of them but there is a case of `{-2,2,-2}`. Then You will always get `-2` unless you restate the question to be more precise that you want positive value from the "equal" set.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11795/5

Comment: so many solutions now ;)

Comment: @rm-rf I don't think this is a duplicate of that question, but it's certainly related.

Comment: The function you added, while interesting, does not appear to preserve the sign of the numbers, therefore I do not believe it is applicable to your problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

(Edited with a slight tweak for a tiny bit more speed)

For the non-duplicate version I am finding this quite fast:

```
f = If[+## > 0, ##] & @@ {Max[#], Min[#]} &

f /@ list
(* {-5, 6, 4, -9} *)
```

Comment: Oh dear, I'm afraid to try this, because I think I'm about to lose. :o)

Comment: Well, in v7 and with my particular test mine is still #1, but +1 for a nice method and making me sweat. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, saved by the version number! On v9 I am getting about 150 ms for your method and 20 ms for mine.

Comment: Interesting; I wonder why `Max` and `Min` are so much faster in v9.  By the way, I think this can be written `If[+## > 0, ##] &[Max @ #, Min @ #] &` which I find a little cleaner.

Comment: Simon, is my method any faster in v9 using `RankedMax`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I agree that it's cleaner to use `[]` than `@@{}`. `RankedMax` is much slower than plain `Max`

Answer (score 14):

I'd use `Ordering`, as [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) did, but with the default sort as it will be much faster:

```
# ~Extract~ Ordering[Abs@#, -1] & /@ list
```

> ```
> {-5, 6, 4, -9}
> ```

If duplicates are required we can substitute Position but [Pinguin Dirk](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5274/pinguin-dirk)'s method is faster.

```
list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}, {1, -2, 2}}

# ~Extract~ (Position[#, Max@#] &@Abs@#) & /@ list
```

> ```
> {{-5}, {6}, {4}, {-9}, {-2, 2}}
> ```

---

Here is a concise use of `Pick` that appears to be competitive for the with-duplicates case:

```
f[a_] := Pick[a, #, Max@#] & @ Abs @ a

f /@ list
```

> ```
> {{-5}, {6}, {4}, {-9}, {-2, 2}}
> ```

Timings in version 7 (`Pick` should be faster in v8 and after):

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]

list = RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {50000, 20}];

# ~Extract~ (Position[#, Max@#] &@Abs@#) & /@ list  // timeAvg
Pick[list, UnitStep[# - Max[#]] & /@ (Abs@list), 1] // timeAvg
f /@ list                                           // timeAvg
```

> 0.2496
>
> 0.2184
>
> 0.1996

Nasser's timings in version 9 are: **0.328, 0.112, 0.203** showing that Pinguin Dirk's code is by far the fastest in recent versions.

And timings for the non-duplicate methods:

```
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {50000, 20}];

# ~Extract~ Ordering[Abs@#, -1] & /@ list                                  // timeAvg
(SortBy[#, Abs] & /@ list)[[All , -1]]                                     // timeAvg
If[+## > 0, ##] & @@ {Max[#], -Max[-#]} & /@ list                          // timeAvg
Pick[Flatten@#, Flatten[Ordering@Ordering@Abs[#] & /@ #], 3] &@list        // timeAvg
MapThread[Extract, {list, Ordering[#, -1, (Abs@#1 < Abs@#2) &] & /@ list}] // timeAvg
Max /@ Pick[list, UnitStep[# - Max[#]] & /@ (Abs@list), 1]                 // timeAvg
```

> 0.078
>
> 0.1092
>
> 0.128
>
> 0.2308
>
> 0.842
>
> 0.2652

Comment: Now why did I not use the simpler `Abs[#]` instead of `(Abs@#1 < Abs@#2)` ?  I do not know. I need more coffee :)

Comment: @Nasser And I need more sleep. :^)

Comment: @Nasser You're running v8 or v9 right?  Could you run my timings on that platform?

Comment: OK, here is the timing again ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FYHeg.png)

Comment: @Nasser Thanks.  It looks like Pinguin Dirk's code is the best so far if duplicates are required.

Comment: Curiously, My timing for the `If` variant departs significantly from yours.  `{0.173074, 0.239675, 0.015363, 0.108219, 1.64944, 0.213241}`.  Mac OS X, v. 9.0.1

Answer (score 13):

With the clarification, I think I can reuse my solution I initially provided by just mapping `Max` over it again:

Old:

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[# - Max[#]] & /@ (Abs@list), 1]
```

New:

```
Max /@ Pick[list, UnitStep[# - Max[#]] & /@ (Abs@list), 1]
```

(note: the old solution returned any value that has max abs value, i.e. `{1,2,-2}` returned `2,-2`).

Based on this new information, this approach is definitely not the best out there, see @Mr.Wizard's answer.

Comment: Yes, I don't expect anything non-compiled to beat my first method for the non-duplicate version, but your method is very nice for the duplicate version; it's a great complement.

Comment: yes, totally agree, @Mr.Wizard. Based on this new information in the question, this is how I tried to save my skin (and the upvotes I got) :) & thanks!

Comment: Actually since the original didn't specify your answer is entirely valid.  If you feel it isn't I'll edit the question to specifically request both ways. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the offer :) I gotta run now anyway, and I think my answer now works in both ways - not as quickly as your idea, but I think the disclaimer is in my answer :)

Answer (score 11):

*Update:* Added to test table below new 3 answers.

I came up with an improvement to my earlier method. Instead of running the Ordering on the original list, why not run it on a much smaller list? of only 3 items !

This new list is first generated from the original list like this:

```
{Abs[#], Max[#], Min[#]} & /@ list
```

Now with only 3 elements in each list, it is much faster to do the same thing as before. 
The idea is to check if first element same as `Abs` of 3rd element. If not, then use the middle element, else use the third. So it is only an `If` added to each element. Min/Max/Abs so the heavy work:

```
If[#[[1]] == Abs@#[[3]],#[[3]], #[[2]]] & /@({Max@Abs[#], Max[#], Min[#]}& /@ list)
```

### UPDATE TIMING

All run on V 9.01, windows 7, 64 bit. Intel core i7.  Using this list

```
  list = RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {50000, 20}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using this list

```
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {50000, 20}];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Appendix

Test code:

```
SetAttributes[timeAvg, HoldFirst]
timeAvg[func_] := 
 Do[If[# > 0.3, Return[#/5^i]] & @@ Timing@Do[func, {5^i}], {i, 0, 15}]
MrWizardPick[a_] := Pick[a, #, Max@#] &@Abs@a  ;
(*list=RandomInteger[{-30,30},{50000,20}];*)
MaxBy[list_, fun_] := list[[First@Ordering[fun /@ list, -1]]];
list = RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {50000, 20}];
gpap = Block[{M, m}, M = Max@#;
    m = Min@#;
    If[M > -m, M, m]] &;

Grid[{
  {"Gpap", gpap /@ list // timeAvg},
  {"Simon", If[+## > 0, ##] & @@ {Max[#], Min[#]} & /@ list // timeAvg},
  {"Nasser", If[#[[1]] == Abs@#[[3]], #[[3]], #[[2]]] & /@ ({Max@Abs[#], Max[#], 
         Min[#]} & /@ list) // timeAvg},
  {"Blackbird",Table[If[
      Min[list[[i]]] < 0 && Abs[Min[list[[i]]]] > Max[list[[i]]], 
      Min[list[[i]]], Max[list[[i]]]], {i, Length[list]}] // timeAvg},
  {"Tom",Pick[Flatten@#, Flatten[Ordering@Ordering@Abs[#] & /@ #], 3] &@ list // timeAvg},
  {"MrWizard", #~Extract~Ordering[Abs@#, -1] & /@ list // timeAvg},
  {"Pinguin",Max /@ Pick[list, UnitStep[# - Max[#]] & /@ (Abs@list), 1] // timeAvg},
  {"Kuba", (SortBy[#, Abs] & /@ list)[[;; , -1]] // timeAvg},
  {"Rojo", Pick[list, 
      With[{absList = Abs@list}, 
       With[{max = Max /@ absList}, # - max & /@ Transpose@absList] //
          Unitize // Transpose], 0] // Flatten // timeAvg},
  {"MrWizardPick", MrWizardPick /@ list // timeAvg},
  {"Szabolcs", MaxBy[#, Abs] & /@ list // timeAvg}
  }, Frame -> All, Alignment -> Left, Spacings -> {.5, 1}]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard corrected and updated. Gpap and Simon tests seem to give an almost identical performance on these 2 lists.

Answer (score 11):

Using the function introduced [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25101/12), it becomes a trivial exercise:

```
MaxBy[#, Abs] & /@ list

(* ==> {-5, 6, 4, -9} *)
```

It's probably not the fastest, but if you're familiar with the pattern, it's the least mental effort solution.

Comment: fyi, just added your test to the test cases above in my post. (too many ways to do the same thing in Mathematica) !

Comment: Thanks @Nasser!  So it turns out that mine *is* the slowest in your benchmark.  But it's good to point out that the timings (and the ranking of methods) depends on the dimensions of the input---small list length vs number of small lists.  If I change it to {5000, 200} from {50000, 20}, the results change considerably.

Comment: @Nasser Simon's seems to win in all situations, regardless of the dimensions of the input.

Comment: @Szabolcs, presumably the relative slowness of `MaxBy` comes from explicitly mapping `Abs` over the list. Perhaps you could include a check to use `f[list]` when `f` is `Listable`.

Comment: I don't like this method.  It's only slightly simpler than my more direct use of `Ordering` and doesn't use `Abs` properly (Listability); I see this as a needless abstraction.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see it as a mental abstraction that helps me arrive at the solution with less effort/thinking and allows me to concentrate on the problem at hand instead of the implementation of a detail.  If you put any effort into solving *this particular problem*, then you'll necessarily arrive at a faster/better solution, such as yours (which is pretty much the same as this one except with better use of `Abs`).

Answer (score 10):

```
list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {2, -9, 6}};
```

One way would be:

```
(SortBy[#, Abs] & /@ list)[[;; , -1]]
```

> ```
> {-5, 6, 4, -9}
> ```

But I bet it is not effective since we do not have to sort each list to obtain this. However for short sublists it may be good approach.

---

Ok, this scans only once but maybe `MapIndexed` is not the fastest scanner:

```
max[_] = 0;
f[z_, {i_, j_}] := max[i] = If[Abs[max[i]] > Abs@z, max[i], z]

MapIndexed[f, list, {2}];

max /@ Range[Length[list]]
```

> ```
> {-5, 6, 4, -9}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so a bit late but I want to play as well. It's a variation on a theme by @SimonWoods:

```
ClearAll@f

f = Block[{M, m},
   M = Max@#;
   m = Min@#;
   If[M < -m, m, M]
   ] &
```

but in my machine it works slightly faster.

```
list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}};
f /@ list
(*out*) {-5, 6, 4, -9}
```

**--EDIT--**

Changed `If[M > -m, M, m]` to `If[M < -m, m, M]` to pick the positive of two numbers with equal absolute value.

Comment: make that >= for the + to win the tie..

Answer (score 6):

I'll join the fun:

```
r = Ordering[#, -1, (Abs@#1 < Abs@#2) &] & /@ list;
MapThread[Extract, {list, r}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

More fun:

`Pick[Flatten@#, Flatten[Ordering@Ordering@Abs[#] & /@ #], 3] &@list`

=> {-5, 6, 4, -9}

Comment: Clever, but it's worth noting that this only works if each sub-list is the same length.

Answer (score 4):

I saw so many answers that I just had to participate. This won't work for a ragged array

```
Pick[list,
  With[{absList = Abs@list},
   With[{max = Max /@ absList},
      # - max & /@ Transpose@absList] // Unitize // Transpose
   ], 0] // Flatten
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Table[If[Min[list[[i]]] < 0, Min[list[[i]]], Max[list[[i]]]], {i, 
  Length[list]}]
```

> {-5, 6, 4, -9}

For
 `list = RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {50000, 20}];`

> Time = 0.040058

```
list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {50000, 20}];
```

> Time = 0.050072

Edit: As a valid mistake found by @simonWoods, I have rectified the snippet and now its generating better result.

```
Table[If[Min[list[[i]]] < 0 && Abs[Min[list[[i]]]] > Max[list[[i]]], 
  Min[list[[i]]], Max[list[[i]]]], {i, Length[list]}]
```

For `list = {{-1, 10}};     (*{10}*)`

For `list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}}    (*{-5, 6, 4, -9}*)`

For `list = {{-1, -10, 10}};   (*{10}*)`

For  `list = RandomInteger[{-30, 30}, {50000, 20}];`

> Time = 0.120173

For  `list = RandomReal[{-9, 9}, {50000, 20}];`

> Time = 0.130187(Ranging from .012.. to .014.. on my system)

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work - try `list = {{-1,10}}` for example

Comment: @SimonWoods: thanks for pointing out the mistake, I have tried fixing it. Can you please verify it once for me.

Comment: Yes, it's working now.

Answer (score 4):

One way to ensure the + wins in the case of equal Abs..

```
(Last@SortBy[ #, {Abs[#], #} & ]) & /@
   {{1, 2, -2}, {1, 5, -5}, {1, -3, 3}, {1, -4}}

(* {2, 5, 3, -4} *)
```

or this may be faster..dont feel like running for time.

```
(Last@SortBy[{Max[#], Min[#]}, Abs]) & /@
  {{1, 2, -2}, {1, -5, 5}, {1, -3, 3}, {1, -4}}
```

Edit -- oops not nesessary SortBy autmaticaly breaks the tie based on signed value so just this works..

```
(Last@SortBy[ #, Abs ]) & /@
   {{1, 2, -2}, {1, 5, -5}, {1, -3, 3}, {1, -4}}
```

"  If some of the f[e_i] are the same, then the canonical order of the corresponding e_i is used. "

Answer (score 2):

In versions 10+, you can use `MaximalBy` and `TakeLargestBy`:

```
list = {{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}};

Flatten[MaximalBy[Abs]/@list]
```

> {-5, 6, 4, -9}

```
Flatten[TakeLargestBy[Abs, 1]/@list]
```

> {-5, 6, 4, -9}

`TakeLargestBy` is the faster of the two. Both are much slower than other methods posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

As first [pointed out](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3131/45431) by @rm-rf, there exist internal, undocumented functions `` Random`Private`MapThreadMin `` and `` Random`Private`MapThreadMax ``, and these are useful for this purpose. Here is a function that uses these internal functions:

```
maxByAbs[list_] := With[{t = Transpose@list},
    With[{min = Random`Private`MapThreadMin[t], max = Random`Private`MapThreadMax[t]},
        max + UnitStep[Abs[min] - max] (min-max)
    ]
]
```

The basic idea is to get the minimum and maximum values of each list, and then use arithmetic to figure out which one is larger. Here is the OP example:

```
maxByAbs[{{1, -3, -5}, {2, 1, 6}, {0, 2, 4}, {-9, 2, 6}}]
```

> {-5, 6, 4, -9}

And here is a brief timing comparison with the chosen answer:

```
list=RandomInteger[{-30,30}, {50000,20}];

f = If[+## > 0, ##] & @@ {Max[#], Min[#]} &;

r1 = f/@list; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = maxByAbs[list]; //RepeatedTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.0068, Null}
>
> {0.0028, Null}
>
> True