# Plot and find intersection points of multiple curves

Tags: plotting, functions, intersection

I tried to plot and find the coordinates of the intersectrions of more than two curves in a the plot. Is there a special way to do this?

Here's my code so yu can visualize the whole thing.

```
m = 9.1*10^-31;
L = .5 ; 
ℏ = 1.055*10^-34;
e = ℏ^2/(2 m) (π/L)^2 (1/(1.602*10^-19));
V1 = 2 e;
V2 = 5 e;
V3 = 8 e;
ν1 = V1/e;
ν2 = V2/e;
ν3 = V3/e;
Plot[
  {Sqrt[ν1 - ϵ], Sqrt[ν2 - ϵ], Sqrt[ν3 - ϵ], Sqrt[ϵ] Tan[π/2 Sqrt[ϵ]], 
   -Sqrt[ϵ] Cot[π/2 Sqrt[ϵ]]}, 
 {ϵ, 0, 10}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You might be interested in the built-in physical constants, e.g., `Entity["PhysicalConstant", "ElectronMass"]["Value"]//QuantityMagnitude`, `Entity["PhysicalConstant", "ReducedPlanckConstant"]["Value"]//QuantityMagnitude`, `Entity["PhysicalConstant", "ElementaryCharge"]["Value"]//QuantityMagnitude`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
plot = Plot[{Sqrt[ν1 - ϵ], Sqrt[ν2 - ϵ], Sqrt[ν3 - ϵ], 
    Sqrt[ϵ] Tan[π/2 Sqrt[ϵ]], -Sqrt[ϵ] Cot[π/2 Sqrt[ϵ]]}, {ϵ, 0, 10}];

Graphics`Mesh`MeshInit[]

intersections = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot];
Show[plot, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@intersections}]
```

[image]

See also: [Marking points of intersection between two curves](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10472/125)

Comment: this is great, thanks, but how do i know the coordinates of the points?

Comment: @Sosa, `intersections` is list of coordinates where two lines intersect.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this non-graphically:

```
m = 9.1*10^-31;
L = .5;
hb = 1.055*10^-34;
e = hb^2/(2 m) (\[Pi]/L)^2 (1/(1.602*10^-19));
V1 = 2 e;
V2 = 5 e;
V3 = 8 e;
v1 = V1/e;
v2 = V2/e;
v3 = V3/e;
f1[x_] = Sqrt[v1 - x];
f2[x_] = Sqrt[v2 - x];
f3[x_] = Sqrt[v3 - x];
f4[x_] = Sqrt[x] Tan[\[Pi]/2 Sqrt[x]];
f5[x_] = -Sqrt[x] Cot[\[Pi]/2 Sqrt[x]];
functions = Plot[Evaluate@Through[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}[x]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
results = Quiet[Partition[
  Flatten[Thread[{#2, #1[#2]}] & @@@ Cases[{#1, 
     ToRules@(Reduce[{#1[x] == #2[x], 0 <= x <= 10}, x])} & @@@ 
       Subsets[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, {2}], {a_, b__} -> {a, 
         ReplaceAll[x, {b}]}]], 2]]

(* {{0.463001, 1.23976}, {1.6379, 0.601749}, {0.600243, 
  2.09756}, {4.67897, 0.566599}, {2.31953, 1.63722}, {0.662803, 
  2.70873}, {5.60865, 1.5464}, {2.60346, 2.32305}}  *)

Show[functions, ListPlot[results, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]