# Finding the maximum of a piecewise function

Tags: piecewise, maximum

I have the following piecewise function of the variable $e_f$:

$$g(a,b,c,w,F,e_h,e_f)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{(c-a e_f) (e_f (4e_f w-a)+c)}{8 b e_f^2} & \left(e_f=e_h\land e_f>\frac{c}{a}\right)\lor e_f\geq \frac{c}{a-2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{F}} \\
       0 & \text{otherwise}
         \end{cases}
$$

where all the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, $w$, $F$, $e_h$ and $e_f$ are strictly positive ($\gt 0$).

```
g[a_, b_, c_, w_, F_, eh_, ef_] := Piecewise[{{
    ((c - a ef) (c + ef (-a + 4 ef w)))/(8 b ef^2),
      (ef == eh && ef > c/a) || ef >= c/(a - 2 Sqrt[b] Sqrt[F])
  }}, 0]
```

For given numerical values of $a$, $b$, $c$, $w$, $F$, and for a given $e_h$, I would like to find the value of $e_f$ that maximises $g$. I tried to use the `FindMaximum` function, but this seems to miss the point where $e_f=e_h$ where the function may be defined and maximised. For example:

`FindMaximum[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef], {ef, 0.2}]` returns `{0., {ef -> 0.2}}`
and `FindMaximum[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef], {ef, 0.3}]` returns `{0.698102, {ef -> 0.272076}}` which is the maximum on the continuous part for $e_f\geq \frac{c}{a-2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{F}}$. So in both cases, the point $e_f=0.24$ where the global maximum $g(10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, 0.24)=0.753472$ is missed.

Ultimately, I would like to plot the argmax of $g(e_f)$ as a function of $e_h$ for given values of the other parameters. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: In this case, you could add the piecewise conditions as constraints on the optimisation

Comment: `Maximize[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef], ef ]  (*{0.698102, {ef -> 0.272076}}*)` gets a little bit closer to the expected maximum.

Comment: `Maximize[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 24/100, ef]` performs `{217/288, {ef -> 6/25}}`.

Comment: @Bill: yes, it was a typo. Sorry about that and thanks for spotting it! I corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef] // N]
```

[image: Result]

I believe these general min/maximize functions use search strategies that start with some initial points, and *Mathematica* doesn't expect that the max point is located at the *isolated* point $e_f=0.24$. Therefore, you may need to treat this specially.

## Method 1

```
If[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, 0.24] > #1,
   0.24, #2[[1, 2]]
   ] & @@ NMaximize[
  FullSimplify[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef]], ef]
```

> ```
> 0.24
> ```

```
Plot[
 If[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, eh] > #1,
    eh, #2[[1, 2]]
    ] & @@ NMaximize[
   FullSimplify[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, ef]], ef],
 {eh, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> {0, Automatic}]
```

> [image: Plot]

## Method 2

Put the special data together with the result of `NMaximize` in same format, and then take the largest data according to the first element (value). This is more general.

```
MaximalBy[
  {
   {g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, 0.24], {ef -> 0.24}},
   NMaximize[FullSimplify@g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef], ef]
   },
  First
  ][[1, 2, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> 0.24
> ```

```
Plot[
 MaximalBy[
   {
    {g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, eh], {ef -> eh}},
    NMaximize[
     FullSimplify@g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, ef], ef]
    }, First
   ][[1, 2, 1, 2]],
 {eh, 0, 0.5},
 PlotRange -> {0, Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(h\)]\)", 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\("\<arg max\>"\), 
SubscriptBox[\(e\), \(f\)]]\) g[Subscript[e, h], Subscript[e, f]]}
 ]
```

> [image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you! I see the difficulty of finding the isolated point. As I am not very advanced with _Mathematica_, just to understand what your code does: the #2 and #1 refer to the output of the `NMaximize`, right? `#2[[1, 2]]` is the value of the maximum? And `#1` is the argmax? So for any `eh` in (0,0.6), if `g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, eh]` is greater than the maximum found through the `NMaximize`, the plot draws `eh`, otherwise it draws the argmax found through the `NMaximize`, is that correct?

Comment: @Lednacek: Oops! The `#1` and `#2[[1,2]]` were misplaced in my code. The plot is incorrect. I'll modify it later. As for what you say, they're right.

Comment: @Lednacek: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is great! I have two more questions regarding your answer: (1) In the plot, where the curve drops vertically, I believe this should be a discontinuity (a jump). Why does it appear as a continuous (vertical) line? (2) Is there any way I can store the relationship plotted (the argmax of g(ef) as a function of `eh`) and use it for some later calculations? In particular, I need to calculate the intersection of the curve plotted with another function that links `ef` and `eh`. Many thanks again!

Comment: @Lednacek: (1) I think it's because we're using functions that are non-differentiable to *Mathematica* like `If` and `NMaximize`, so the discontinuities are not detected. I can't think of a good solution but you can take a look at a related question: [10501](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10501/plotting-discontinuous-functions-without-spurious-vertical-segments). (2) Related question: [199037](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199037/plot-and-find-intersection-points-of-multiple-curves).

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

First consider the valid region of the parameters `eh,ef`

```
cond[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ,F_?NumericQ ] := (ef == eh && ef > c/a) ||ef >= c/(a - 2 Sqrt[b] Sqrt[F]) 
RegionPlot[ cond[10, 1, 1, 5, 10] , {ef, .2, .3} , {eh, 0.23, .28},PlotPoints -> {100, {eh == ef}}, FrameLabel -> Automatic,Prolog -> {Red, Point[{.24, .24}]}]
```

[image]

The plot shows that the point `ef==eh==.24` you expect the maximum isn't allowed!

NMaximize evaluates the maximum

```
Maximize[g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 0.24, ef], ef ]  (*{0.698102, {ef -> 0.272076}}*)
```

**addendum**

Obviously Mathematica didn't find the complete valid region.
But `Maximize` is able to solve  the problem if you add  the constraints  `ef > 0, eh > 0` and maximize in two dimensions  `{ef,eh}`:

```
Maximize[{g [10, 1, 1, 5, 10, eh, ef], ef > 0, eh > 0}, {ef, eh}] // N
(*{0.753847, {ef -> 0.242362, eh -> 0.242362}}*)
```

**final addendum**

If you are looking for a maximum for given parameters `a, b, c, w, F, eh` define a region depending on these parameters

```
reg[a_, b_, c_, w_, F_, eh_] =ImplicitRegion[(ef == eh && ef > c/a) ||ef >= c/(a - 2 Sqrt[b] Sqrt[F]), ef ]
```

and maximize

```
NMaximize[ g [10, 1, 1, 5, 10, .24, ef]  , Element[{ef}, reg [10, 1, 1, 5, 10, .24]]] 
(*{0.753472, {ef -> 0.24}}*)
```

Comment: How about `g[10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 24/100, 24/100]` which produces `217/288`? See my comment to the question.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, but the point `eh=ef=.24` lies outside the valid region!

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see what is this "valid region"? The function g is defined for any positive `ef`. It is given by the expression in the first line when `ef>c/(a - 2 Sqrt[b] Sqrt[F])` OR when `ef>c/a AND ef=eh`. (Otherwise, it is zero.) So `eh=ef=.24>1/10` is a valid point and it corresponds indeed to the maximum that I would like to be able to find, but don't know how.

Comment: Yes, that's the region plotted in my answer!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: But the region on which the function g is given by the formula should also include the diagonal  `ef=eh` for any `ef>0.1` so on your diagram, on the left of the blue-shaded region, there should be an upward-sloping line representing `ef=eh`.

Comment: @Lednacek Possibly that means it's a problem of the region function, which cannot find the onedimensional subregion `ef==eh` !

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you for the addendum! Interesting to know about the two-dimensional maximisation. But it does not solve my problem. I need to maximise g for given values of `eh` in order to obtain the relationship between the argmax of g(ef) and eh, denoted for example by ef(eh). From a different maximisation, I will obtain another relationship eh(ef). Then I need to determine the crossing of these two _reaction functions_.

Comment: @Lednacek Perhaps my **final addendum** shows the way to solve your problem.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Thank you, this is great! What's the best way to use your method in the final addendum to obtain the results for a whole region of eh? I.e. to "construct" the function ef(eh)? To write a loop and maximise for each increment of the loop and then stock all the results somehow? Or is there a more elegant way? Many thanks again!

Comment: @ Lednacek That's the way I think!