# find a maximum parameter for a range of target eigenvalues as a function of matrix dimension

Tags: matrix, symbolic, eigenvalues, parameters

I have a symbolic tridiagonal matrix of this form

```
a = 0;
c = 0.25;
sa1[b_] :=SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, 
          Band[{2, 1}, {2 l, 2 l}] -> {I b/4, I c}, 
          Band[{1, 2}, {2 l, 2 l}] -> {-I b/4, -I c}}, {2 l, 2 l}];
```

where *a* and *c* are fixed parameters, *b*>0 is a varying parameter and *l* is the rank of the matrix. By diagonalizing this matrix as a function of *b*, I can obtain the largest value for *b*, let's say *bmax*, such that the absolute value of the eigenvalues is less than 1/10^5. Note that the eignevalues always appear in pairs by symmetry. To find *bmax*, I have employed the Arnoldi method which has been employed also in this [thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194807/efficiently-find-all-values-of-parameter-such-that-any-of-the-eigenvalues-of-a-m)

```
closestEVtotarget[b_?NumericQ, target_?NumericQ] := 
  Abs[First@
    Eigenvalues[sa1[N[b]], -1, 
     Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", 
       "Shift" -> target}]];
With[{target = 1/10^5}, 
  Plot[closestEVtotarget[b, target], {b, 0, 0.5}, 
   GridLines -> {None, {target}}]];
With[{target = 1/10^5}, 
  plot = Plot[{target, closestEVtotarget[b, target]}, {b, 0, 2}]; 
  bmaxval = Graphics`Mesh`FindIntersections[plot]];
```

For instance for *l*=6, printing the *bmaxval* would be

```
{{0.185999,0.00001}}
```

where *bmax*=0.185999.
Now the question is how I can collect all *bmax* values for different even values of *l*, let's say

```
llist = {4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26};
```

and plot *l* vs. *bmax*?

Comment: Did you mean to say "...such that the absolute value of the *smallest* eigenvalues is less than 1/10^5"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define the matrix with [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html):

```
a = 0;
c = 0.25;
sa1[l_Integer] := sa1[l] = Function[b, 
  Evaluate@SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> a, 
    Band[{2, 1}, {2 l, 2 l}] -> {I b/4, I c}, 
    Band[{1, 2}, {2 l, 2 l}] -> {-I b/4, -I c}}, {2 l, 2 l}]]
```

calculate the smallest eigenvalue by absolute value:

```
ev[l_Integer, b_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[sa1[l][b], -1, Method -> "Arnoldi"][[1]]
```

find the spot where the smallest eigenvalue is equal to $10^{-5}$:

```
Table[{l, b /. FindRoot[ev[l, b] == 10^-5, {b, 0.5}]}, {l, 4, 26, 2}]
```

> {{4, 0.0796537}, {6, 0.18602}, {8, 0.285008}, {10, 0.368593}, {12, 
>     0.437727}, {14, 0.494971}, {16, 0.542751}, {18, 0.583032}, {20, 
>     0.617337}, {22, 0.646833}, {24, 0.672422}, {26, 0.6948}}

```
ListPlot[%]
```

[image]

Comment: This works very nicely. For ranks>50 I have encountered incorrect solutions which have been fixed by replacing {b,0.5} by {b,1.0}.  Thank you.