# Is it possible to use `ContourPlot` for specific eigenvalue of a large matrix Mn(x,y)?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, eigenvalues

I have a large matrix, say `En En`, as a function of two variables `x` and `y` which has `En` eigenvalues. I want to use `ContourPlot` to show specific eigenvalue, say `(En/2)+1` with respect to `x` and `y`. For small `En` this can be done but it did not work for large `En`. For example, with `En=8` it gives the desired result, but for larger `En` not working.

```
M1={{0, I Sin[x] + Sin[y], 3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1}, {-I Sin[x] + Sin[y],
   0, -1, 3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y]}, {3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], -1, 
  0, -I Sin[x] - Sin[y]}, {-1, 3 - Cos[x] - Cos[y], I Sin[x] - Sin[y],
   0}};

tc={{0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0, 0}};

Mn[n_] := 
 SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {M1}, 
   Band[{1, 5}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {tc}, 
   Band[{5, 1}, {4 n, 4 n}] -> {ConjugateTranspose[tc]}}]

 w = 2; En = 4 w;(*w must be >1*)
ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[Eigenvalues[N@Mn[w]][[En/2 + 1]] == 0.4], {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Blue]
```

this is the result with `w=2` (i.e `En=8`) How can I do the same for `w=40` (`En=160`)?

[image]

I try `w=3` and got this error "Eigenvalues::eival: Unable to find all roots of the characteristic polynomial." and this is the final output:

[image]

Comment: What specific problem do you observe with `w=40`? (Does it give a blank graph, an error message,...)

Comment: it gives error: Eigenvalues::eival: Unable to find all roots of the characteristic polynomial. and then the output is messy. I updated the question with w=3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to calculate the eigenvalues explicitly; it is enough to check that the characteristic polynomial has a zero. If you calculate the determinant numerically for specific numerical values of $x$, $y$, and the eigenvalue, then the characteristic polynomial can be circumvented and more stable algorithms can be applied:

```
MM[x_, y_] = Mn[w];
f[λ_?NumericQ, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := 
  Det[MM[x, y] - λ*IdentityMatrix[En]]

With[{λ = 0.4}, 
  ContourPlot[f[λ, {x, y}] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the trick of [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197946/26598): for given $(x,y)$, calculate the eigenvalue that is closest to $\lambda$ by using a shifted Arnoldi-Lanczos iteration, and then contour-plot the difference between this eigenvalue and $\lambda$. This method is much faster and much more stable, but generates spurious contours whenever there's a switch from one eigenvalue branch to another:

```
g[λ_?NumericQ, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}] := 
  Eigenvalues[MM[x, y], 1, 
              Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "Magnitude", 
                         "Shift" -> λ}][[1]] - λ

With[{λ = 0.4}, 
  ContourPlot[g[λ, {x, y}] == 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow,this is perfect, thanks! Is there a way to smooth the results?

Comment: @HD2006 see my update for a different, smoother algorithm. Also, the `PlotPoints` option can help.

Comment: I still need your help with one more thing that will be a great help. Can I get the values of `{x, y}` coincide with each contour? I really need this, may you please help me?

Comment: I suggest you ask a fresh question for this issue.