# Compute the stationary distribution of a large transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I am doing some simulations for simple random walks on directed random graphs. From a graph of `n` vertices, I get a `n` by `n` transition probability matrix `transit`, with `2 n` non-zero entries. I would like to compute the stationary distribution `pi` (a vector of `n` non-negative entries which sum to one), such that `pi * transit == pi`.

Currently, I found two ways to do this. The first is to use `NullSpace`.

```
eigenVector=First[NullSpace[N[transit]-IdentityMatrix[n]]];
pi=eigenVector/Total[eigenVector]
```

The second is to define a Markov Process directly on the underline graph `g` and use `StationaryDistribution` as follows.

```
n=VertexCount[g];
mp=DiscreteMarkovProcess[1,g];
stationary=StationaryDistribution[mp];
pi=NProbability[x==#,x\[Distributed]stationary]&/@Range[n]
```

Both methods can handle about `n = 2000` on my laptop. But I would really like to compute this for a bit higher `n`. Any suggestions?

---

Update: For example `g` and `transit` with 1000, 2000, 3000 and 4000 nodes, see this [link](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=kZAwtzXZeGaJTVMsMj8WgNOsuehov4bDFiiy).

Comment: I’ve got some ideas but can you supply examples of transit and g?

Comment: @ChrisK Thanks. I have prepared a .wl file. Please see the edit.

Comment: When you compute the null space, is the matrix comprised of exact of approximate numbers? At the size range in question, I would expect serious memory issues unless it is machine reals (or complexes, but that won't be the case in this particular scenario).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I actually turns `transit` to numeric values before calling `NullSpace`. I have updated the code.

Comment: Could you also give a smaller example so that we can compare the results against your methods?

Comment: @ChrisK I have created 4 files for different `n`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may run into memory problems because you are constructing a full matrix with `IdentityMatrix[n]` instead of a sparse one with `IdentityMatrix[n, SparseArray]`. By using a sparse identity matrix you can do 4000x4000 in about 8 seconds, without excessive memory use:

```
Dimensions[transit]
(*    {4000, 4000}    *)

eigenVector = First[NullSpace[
  N[transit - IdentityMatrix[Dimensions[transit], SparseArray]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    8.32465    *)
```

Just make sure you keep all matrices sparse and never construct a full ("normal") matrix.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing this out. With this improvement, I can now deal with 4000x4000 matrix, though with as much as 60 seconds time. I guess the big time difference is because there is a of problem with the examples I provided. I have updated them now. Can you try the 4000x4000 one again?

Comment: Even after your update it still takes 8 seconds on my laptop. Maybe your computer is just slow.

Comment: Yeah, it could just be my laptop is bit slow. Thanks. I am happy with the current performance anyway.

Answer (score 6):

**edit:** it's even simpler since this is a discrete-time Markov chain

I didn't know Roman's trick with `SparseArray`.  Here's another trick: use `Method->"Arnoldi"`, asking for only the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue (approx. one) using `1`, which is the stationary distribution.

```
evNull=First[NullSpace[N[transit]-IdentityMatrix[4000,SparseArray]]];//AbsoluteTiming
(* 15.6608 -- I must need a faster computer! *)

evArnoldi=Eigenvectors[N@transit,1,Method->{"Arnoldi"}][[1]];//AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.024535 *)
```

So there's another couple of orders-of-magnitude speedup for you.  I'm not patient enough to wait for `StationaryDistribution` to finish!

The eigenvectors look the same when plotted BTW.

Comment: In this case it would be advantageous to point the Arnoldi algorithm towards the "right" eigenvalue by using a `Shift` operation: [see this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197946/26598). In the present example you got lucky to catch the right eigenvalue.

Comment: @Roman True in general, but in this case I don't think it's luck, because all eigenvalues should be nonpositive except the one associated with the stationary distribution, which should be zero (conservation of probability).  See https://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa19/handout_Lecture4_2019.pdf for that last point.  At least I hope this is true, because we're using this technique in a paper now :)

Comment: I should add, I'm a bit unclear on OP's actual problem, whether it is a continuous- or discrete-time process and the role of the `-IdentityMatrix[n]` part here.

Comment: Agreed, you're right that if the matrix is constructed correctly, it will have the right spectral property.

Comment: @Roman Upon closer reading of the problem, it's clear that it's a discrete-time Markov chain, so the solution is even easier (and doesn't require `IdentityMatrix` at all).

Comment: @ChrisK Yes. This is very fast. Thanks.