# Using the symbol I for electrical current

Tags: symbols, custom-notation, built-in-symbols

I would like to use the I as a symbol for the electrical current. How can I redefine it, so it is not interpreted as the imaginary unity?

Comment: I thought you guys used J or j?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing so since complex numbers are fundamental in *Mathematica*. Instead, you should use some other symbol, which you can easily make print as "I" if you so wish.

Comment: Yes, we use j for the imaginary unit, and i and I for currents. But if I use I for a current, mathematica interprets it as the imaginary unity. So, how can I get Mathematica to interpret I as my own symbol instead of the imaginary Unit?

Comment: @Diegos Do you find using `\[CapitalIota]` unacceptable?  If you *really* want to use raw `I` I'll show you how, but using it is against my better judgement.

Comment: Thank you, I will use capital iota

Comment: Mathematica is a programming language, and therefore it has constraints on the notation you can use.  It is much more flexible in this regard than other languages, but it still has a precise syntax that you need to follow.  You'll have to adapt to it instead of trying to force it to adapt to you, otherwise you're just asking for trouble.

Comment: I would do it like this: `Module[{I}, (*Stuff with I*) ]`.

Answer (score 20):

The short answer is *don't do it*.  Really, it's just not a good idea.  You can use other symbols, such as `\[CapitalIota]` which looks almost exactly like `I` and is entered with <kbd>Esc</kbd>`I`<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

---

If you're really determined you could [substitute](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1123/121) symbols using `$PreRead` and `MakeBoxes` but again I don't recommend it.  For example:

```
MakeBoxes[I, _] := "\[ImaginaryJ]"

MakeBoxes[currentI, _] := "I"

$PreRead = # /. {"I" -> "currentI", "j" -> "I"} &;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I understand your recomandation Oleksandr, but what sense does it make for Mathematica to permit using j as imaginary unity (typical in electrotechnics), if I is still reserved (so not accessible to symbolise currents)? Consequently using j as imaginary unity, should permit to use I as current

Comment: @Diegos *Mathematica* isn't set up to make those kinds of changes, perhaps unfortunately.  In the long run you will almost certainly want to find alternatives to what you are describing.

Comment: Thank you anyways, I will use capital iota in this case. But it would certainly be an improvement, if in a future time one could replace predefined symbols for one's own computations: something like a "local redefinition bracket".

Comment: @Diegos I added an example to my answer that may interest you.  When you say "local redefinition bracket" do you mean something like Leonid used [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/377/121)?  That is possible.