# Match groups in regular expressions

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I'm trying to understand *Mathematica's* pattern matching in strings, but I have some doubts.

99% of the time I need to a) check if a match occurs and b) retrieve the matched patterns.

I come from perl, where it is easy to do both in two lines:

```
"big bad wolf =~ / (.*) /;
print"$1\n"
```

> ```
> "bad"
> ```

In *Mathematica* is it possible to do it with just one function call? For now I'm able to do

```
a = "big bad wolf"
StringMatchQ[a, RegularExpression["big .* wolf"]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
StringCases[a, RegularExpression[" (.*) "] -> "$1"]
```

> ```
> {"bad"}
> ```

As a 2nd question -- how can I retrieve more than one pattern, e.g. from this call:

```
StringCases[a, RegularExpression["(.*) .* (.*)"]
```

Comment: Quite likely I am misunderstanding your first question, but since you know `RegularExpression[]` and `StringCases[]` already, why do they not suit your needs? If nothing is matched, you end up with an empty list.

Comment: sorry I wasnt clear... I just wanted to know if in M there is a single function able to return False on no-match, and {\$1,\$2,...} in case of a match ...

Comment: So, something like `With[{s = StringCases[(* stuff *)]}, If[s =!= {}, s, False]]`?

Comment: _Mathematica_'s regular expression matching capabilities are not up to perl's, but it does handle match groups. You need to make a careful reading of the full documentation article on `RegularExpression`. Frankly, for heavy duty reggae work, I prefer Ruby to _Mathematica_.

Comment: @m_goldberg reggae work?

Comment: @Mr. Wizard -- that's when m_goldberg is programming for Bob Marley.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, et al. Hate to spoil the fun, but -- alas -- I intended to write 'regex work' ()you probably already guessed). At least my conscious mind so intended. The real control center evidently had other things in mind. Never programmed for Marley -- probably missed a good gig :-)

Comment: @m_goldberg My actual guess was industry jargon of some sort.  As for "real control center" I find that amusing; at one point I noticed that nearly all my typos were actual words.  Fingers seem to have a mind of their own at times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a minor variation on the last example in the Examples > Generalizations & Extensions section of [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegularExpression.html),

```
StringCases["big bad wolf", RegularExpression["(.*) .* (.*)"] -> {"$1", "$2"}]
```

> ```
> {{"big", "wolf"}}
> ```

Does this work for you?

Comment: perfectly, thanks! I'm just surprised it doesnt return {"big", "wolf"}: why is it one level deeper?

Comment: @alessandro That is because of the right hand side of the `Rule`; if you use `RegularExpression["(.*) .* (.*)"] -> foo["$1", "$2"]` you will see `foo` instead.  If you want a flat list you could use `RegularExpression["(.*) .* (.*)"] -> Sequence["$1", "$2"]` or `Flatten @ StringCases[ . . . ]`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for a pattern structure like this:

```
str = "big bad wolf";
StringCases[str, "big " ~~ x__ ~~ " wolf" -> x]
```

which returns `bad` or whatever happens to lie between big and wolf. In the event that there is no match, you get a null {}.

Comment: Yes, I simply use RegularExpression because, frankly, Wolfram's syntax for RE's is so ugly! (personal opinion :-)

Comment: @alessandro The *Mathematica* string pattern syntax is an extension of the native pattern syntax; its strength is that is familiar and very flexible (e.g. extensible with `Condition`) but like [most aspects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/344/121) of *Mathematica* it is a bit clumsy with Strings. To the extent possible *Mathematica* actually converts string patterns into regular expressions so if you are comfortable writing them directly you might as well do that, with one caveat: [Why is StringExpression faster than RegularExpression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25677/121)